# Access DebugElement of nested component when using native view encapsulation

Tags: unit-testing, angular, typescript, shadow-dom

I'm testing a component like the following

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: `
    <my-nested-component [state]="state"></my-nested-component>
  `,
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native
})
export class MyComponent {}
```

When unit testing my component, I want to obtain a reference to the nested component `MyOtherComponent`. If `my-component` used no encapsulation, or if it used emulated encapsulation, I could use:

```
let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
let nestedComponent = fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(MyNestedComponent))
```

to obtain a reference to the component.

But in this case, `query` just queries the light DOM children of the component (mimicking the behaviour of `querySelector`), so `nestedComponent` is `null` when using native view encapsulation.

How are you supposed to get a reference to the `DebugElement` (and therefore the component instance) of the nested component?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's say we have the following components:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-nested-component',
  template: `
    <h1>Nested component - {{ state }}</h1> 
  `,
})
export class NesterComponent {
  @Input() state: number;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <my-nested-component [state]="state"></my-nested-component> 
  `,
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native
})
export class TestComponent {
  state = 1;
}
```

So i would write test like this:

```
let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
let component = fixture.componentInstance;

const shadowRoot: DocumentFragment = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.shadowRoot;
const nestedComponentNativeElement = shadowRoot.querySelector('my-nested-component');

const nestedComponentDebugElement = <DebugElement>getDebugNode(nestedComponentNativeElement);

var nestedComponentInstance: NesterComponent = nestedComponentDebugElement.componentInstance;
// here can be your code

component.state = 2;
fixture.detectChanges();

de = nestedComponentDebugElement.query(By.css('h1'));

expect(de.nativeElement.textContent).toBe('Nested component - 2');
```

You can also try this test as a **[live example](https://plnkr.co/edit/zqZXiOOQgjors550AkQw?p=preview)** in plunker

Comment: Where does `getDebugNode` come from? It's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: It is from @angular/core

Comment: ahah! Thank you very much. Answer accepted and bounty awarded (or rather, bounty awarded in 5 hours when it unlocks).

Comment: This led me to the right answer, thank you very much...make sure you declare MyNestedComponent in TestBed.configureTestModule() declarations

Comment: Is the `shadowRoot` really necessary? On Angular 6 I did `getDebugNode(fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('some-component')).componentInstance;` and it worked as expected.

Comment: I also got it working without the `.shadowRoot` (e.g. `const shadowRoot: DocumentFragment = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement`). Actually `.shadowRoot` was null.

Answer (score 5):

Let me update the correct answer based on newer versions of used tools:

Here's how it worked for me, using `"@angular/core": "^5.2.6"`, `"typescript": "~2.4.2"` and `"jasmine-core": "2.5.2"`

```
const shadowRoot: DocumentFragment = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement
const nativeElement = shadowRoot.querySelector("html-element")
const debugElement = getDebugNode(nativeElement) as DebugElement
const instance: NestedComponent = debugElement.componentInstance
expect(debugElement.query(By.css("h1")).nativeElement.textContent).toBe("ExpectedText")
```

Comment: Not using .shadowRoot as shown above worked for me on Angular 7+

Answer (score -1):

With **Angular v6.1.8** and component with **Shadow root**.
Example:

```
  const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
  const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance as AppComponent;
  const shadowRoot: DocumentFragment = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.shadowRoot;

  app.active = true;
  app.title = 'Title';
  fixture.detectChanges();

  expect(shadowRoot.querySelector('.bz-modal__header_title').textContent).toEqual('Title');
```

Comment: for me shadowRoot is null

Comment: I had the same problem and needed to remove the `.shadowRoot` above. See @Matheus CAS answer or my comment on @yurzui's answer.